# Jython, Django with Sqlite3

Tags: django, sqlite, jython

Now I create project by using jython 2.5.2b2 and django1.1.1 (lucid) , after download sqlitejdbc-v056.jar and do some syncdb task it's shown

```
"zxJDBC.Error: auth_permission.content_type_id may not be NULL [SQLCode: 0]"
```

but still can runserver, anyone has some great example for this situation?

Comment: Have you tried comparing it with any other DB's like Postgres or MySQL to see if you get the same effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recreated this error on OS X with Jython 2.5.2 and Django 1.1.1. However the documentation for the 'django-jython' package (which provide the glue between Django on Jython and various databases) has the following on [SQLite3 support](http://packages.python.org/django-jython/database-backends.html#sqlite3):

> **SQLite3**
>
> Experimental. By now, use it only if you are working on improving it.
>   Or if you are really adventurous.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reorder django.contrib.auth in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py
From

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    )
```

To

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (        
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    )
```